# How to download the latest dev version of PHPword using composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpword

Some months ago I have installed PHPword using composer in my cakephp project. Lately we face some limitations and for our happiness the version at github has a lot of updates that meet with ours needs.

We have tried **composer update** but the latest version still a 2016 version 
After that we have tried this:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword:dev
```

The result was:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package phpoffice/phpword dev exists as phpoffice/phpword[0.
10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.12.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, dev-dev
elop, dev-master, v0.12.1, v0.13.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

EDIT: our require composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.4.*",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
        "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.1",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
        "box/spout": "^2.7",
        "cakecoded/ckeditor": "^1.0",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "dev-master",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.0",
        "fgrosse/phpasn1": "^2.0",
        "sop/asn1": "^2.0",
        "sop/x509": "^0.5.0"
    },
```

So, Is there any way to get the last version even in development?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the cause of the conflict is without at least the `require` sections of your composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
$ composer require phpoffice/phpword:dev-master
```

and if that doesn't work, adjust your `composer.json` to include

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable: true
}
```

For reference, see

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable

#### Note

As pointed out, if you have issues installing packages with `composer`, it's a good idea to share your `composer.json` so we can help better.

Comment: Hi, I have a composer.json in my project folder and another one inside vendor\phpoffice\phpword Which of them I need to change?

Comment: The one in your project - the ones you will find in `vendor/` are those of the packages you require.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency to your composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
       "phpoffice/phpword": "v0.13.*"
    }
}
```

and then try running

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

you can now use version dev-master, or wait a couple of days to get the official 0.14 version.